# How to get an IP address for MS SQL Cluster network configuration?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2019, failovercluster

I just started a new internship and have been tasked to set up a SQL failover cluster. They gave me 3 virtual machines to use and when I started I knew nothing. I've been doing a lot of research the last few days and finally set up the iSCSI, got all the nodes together etc. After I went to start the new SQL Server failover cluster installation through the SQL server installation center, I get to the cluster network configuration part and they are asking me to enter an IP address. I assumed it would be the one I got from the SQL server on this node, but it says it already in use. Am I supposed to assign a new one to the failover cluster? If I am to assign a new one, where do I get it? I can't just type a bunch of random numbers and hope for the best. I am using windows server 2019 on all the VM's

Comment: This is HA IP. And person who give you the task should give you the IP.

Comment: They gave me 3 blank VM's with windows server installed. All on it's own domain. Will he have access to the information? When I've asked a question before he said that I need to create everything since the VM's are mine to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean the shared IP address which will be used by the cluster. In this case you need to pick unused IP from the network subnet your servers are on.

Let say your servers have addresses 192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.2 and 192.168.0.3
They also have network mask 255.255.255.0
This means that potentially you can choose any ip from 192.168.0.4 to 192.168.0.254 to be used as shared cluster IP.

To verify if IP address is in use on the network, from one of the servers ping the address and then run `arp -a` command to make sure it is not in the ARP table. Checking ARP table is necessary because devices might be configured to not to reply to ping requests. If you see the address in question replying to pings ir in present in ARP table, it means it is in use so just move to verifying the next one

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much. Like I said I am very new to all of this, so I'll probably be asking a lot of questions on the site